# Pulling Color Scheme from Cell and Applying to Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro put in place to cover over the comment indicators (generally red) so that it would blend in with the color of the cell. I was wondering what additions I needed to make to this macro so that it would instead pull the color scheme from the cell its referencing and place that value for the color scheme?

```
Option Explicit

Sub CoverCommentIndicator()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cmt As Comment
Dim rngCmt As Range
Dim shpCmt As Shape
Dim shpW As Double 'shape width
Dim shpH As Double 'shape height

Set ws = ActiveSheet
shpW = 6
shpH = 4

For Each cmt In ws.Comments
  Set rngCmt = cmt.Parent
  With rngCmt
    Set shpCmt = ws.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRightTriangle, _
      rngCmt.Offset(0, 1).Left - shpW, .Top, shpW, shpH)
  End With
  With shpCmt
    .Flip msoFlipVertical
    .Flip msoFlipHorizontal
    .Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 10
    .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    .Fill.Solid
    .Line.Visible = msoFalse
  End With
Next cmt
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to add your comments as an Input Message under Data Validation? Then your comments will appear when the cell is selected, but there is no indicator placed in the cell.

Comment: As of right now I'm working towards figuring out how I would do this but a macro is most logical with a comment. I need a comment on each cell in reference to the values of multiple cells on another worksheet. As far as I know, not possible to do with input message through data validation but might be possible with macros.

Comment: You can use the `.Validation.InputMessage` property of a cell to set your input message in a macro if needed. I tend to avoid adding unnecessary shapes to Excel sheets because they can cause other unintended issues as well; especially if they are invisible.

Comment: Once I start working on a macro, I'll give it a shot. The shapes has already been causing issues just depending on the person's zoom.

Comment: Sounds good. I will add it as an answer. Let me know if you have any questions once you try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding shapes to the cells and trying to match cell colors, just add your comment as an Input Message under Data Validation. Then your comments will appear when the cell is selected, but there is no indicator placed in the cell.

If you need to do this with a macro, you can use the `.Validation.InputMessage` property of a cell to set your input message. Try it once with the macro recorder and then modify the code to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This should cover it:

```
.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = cmt.Parent.Interior.ColorIndex + 2 ' + 2 just a number to let the color be different from the color index in the cell
```

Also, I think it's a good idea to [enum the colors](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=53791) you may define for this.

Comment: The code still seems to be making it the cover red. With enuming colors, I have about 7 different colors I will be using but they change depending on the conditions I have set, is there a nice way to embed them into a macro? I'm a VBA newbie trying to learn as much as I can, let me give that code a shot though.

Comment: you could set the color indexes to variables and then in your condition code just say myCell.Interior.ColorIndex = variable1. Or you could say myCell.Interior.ColorIndex = myCell2.Interior.ColorIndex to match it with another cell's color

Comment: @adrenom that's strange, I tested it and works, have you tried different color combinations? Please note, this doesn't change the original color, this is just a nice workaround that adds a shape to the cell to mimic the "arrow" from comments, I don't think there's a a way to change the original one.

Comment: I actually tried it with the "+ 2" aspect and it works however without it, it doesn't seem to copy the parent cell color scheme.

Comment: @adrenom that's strange, have you tried to store it in a previous variable and then re use?